# Command definition syntax

Tags: command-line, bash

What is the name and where I can find info about syntax that defines commands:

```
cmake [{-D <var>=<value>}...] -P <cmake-script-file> [-- <unparsed-options>...]
```

What does `[]` , `{}` and `...` means in this definition. I have feeling, that `[]` means `optinal`, but this means that -P should persist always?

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/cmake.1.html

Comment: I know where is location of cmake manual. I found this type of command definition in other commands and would like to get more info on definition language itself.

Answer (score 0):

In general, `[ ]` means "optional". In this case `{ }` is used to group the "`-D`" with the following "`<var>=<value>`". The following "`...`" means the "`-D <var>=<value>`" can be repeated 0 or many times. The "`-P <cmake-script-file>`" is NOT optional.